# how to cout irreducible fraction like 1/2 in c++

Tags: c++, math

I'm trying to solve a [problem](http://codeforces.com/contest/9/problem/A) in codeforces and the output must be in format «A/B» I want to output 1/2 not 0.5 but I don't know how to make the output in this format any help ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


    int main(){
        int A, B, big = 0, i = 1;
        double result = 0;
        cin>>A>>B;
        if(A == B)
            cout<<1/1<<endl;
        if(A > B)
            big = A;
        else
            big = B;

        for( i ; big != 6 ; i++){
            big++;
        }

        cout<<i/6.0<<endl;
        system("pause");
    }
```

Comment: Can't you just output `A`, then a slash, then `B`? Shown the code you have.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please clarify.

Comment: You have to manage the numerator and the denominator as two diffrent integars, and display them as requested.  But please, if you do problems try to solve them vefore asking here....

Comment: ***Show Code***

Comment: Exactly what result do you have that you want to output that way. Two integers for a fraction, a single floating-point value, or something else?

Comment: I want to output 1/2 not 0.5

Comment: I already solve the problem but I can't output 1/2 only the program output 0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of values you need to consider is so short, you can do it as a switch-case:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Y, W;

   cin>>Y>>W;

   switch( max(Y,W) )
   {
    case 1: cout << "1/1" << endl; break;
    case 2: cout << "5/6" << endl; break;
    case 3: cout << "2/3" << endl; break;
    case 4: cout << "1/2" << endl; break;
    case 5: cout << "1/3" << endl; break;
    case 6: cout << "1/6" << endl; break;
   }
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```